# Lang::get in artisan command not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-artisan

Heyo!
I'm working on a school project with Laravel 4.2 and I'm trying to create PDF report based on some data I fetch from the database. Everything works as it should but there is a problem with localization. The `Lang::get()` does NOT work when called form controller or view, but the PDFD.php is formatted correctly.

```
$result_table ="<table><tr><th>".Lang::get('PDFD.foo', array(), $loca)."</th><th>".Lang::get('PDFD.bar', array(), $loca)."</th><th>".Lang::get('PDFD.bas', array(), $loca)."</th></tr>";
```

The code above should generate table headers in the chosen language, but instead it returns the keys even though there should be corresponding values in the `lang/en/PDFD.php` file.

I'm using TCPDF to create the pdf file but I can't see how that would the cause of this porblem...

Any ideas how to fix this? And is it even possible to use localization in artisan commands?

Comment: The file should be located in `lang/{locale}/PDFD.php`, not just `lang/PDFD.php` as you've stated

Comment: My bad. I fixed the path in the question since that isn't the porblem.

Comment: And I assume PDFD.php contains `<?php return ['foo' => 'foo', 'bar' => 'bar', 'bas' => 'bas'];` ?

Comment: "It should." Said my brain, but as it turns out it doesn't it was missing the `return` statement from the PDFD.php... Added the satement and now it's working like a charm.

Comment: Are you using namespaces? try to add a backslash to the lang like this \Lang::get()

Comment: what your default language, see under config/app

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Ben Swinburne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/769237/ben-swinburne) I realized that PDFD.php was missing the `return` statement from the beginning of the file. Adding the statement made the program run like a charm.

Lesson: Never assume that the problem is automatically something complex and begin debugging with the simplest possible solution.